# How Make crystal report as read only cursor as hand

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, cursor, readonly

I'm using crystal report in c# windows form application.here I display some data from database

here my question is that i need make my crystal report as  read only and the cursor as hand symbol like this 
[image] how to add this cursor on my crystal report.

image

[image]

when i click some text in crystal report it as been selected . i no need that i need my crystal report as read only no need to select any thing eg its a like pdf reader.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Steps to make crystal report as read only:

1.Go to report option under file.

2.Select the read only option for this report.

[image]

Comment: its not like that i need my crystal report as read only. see my questionimage

Comment: that is my crystal report when i click some text in crystal report it as been selected . i no need that i need my crystal report as read only no need to select any thing

Comment: i got it but read only option is not in my report option see my question img :-(